# why "ls *bash*" doesn't show the .bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards

I cd to my home directory and typed

```
ls *bash*
```

expecting it will show a list of files contains "bash". However it is not.

While, typing

```
ls .bash*
```

works.

According to the documentation, `*` stands for any character, right? But it seems that it doesn't represent `.` in this case. What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dotglob` shell option controls this:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls *bash*
.bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc
```

It is not enabled by default, probably as a usability/safety measure, since most end users don't have to worry about dotfiles and could very easily delete critical home directory files (such as `.config`, `.ssh`) by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Most shells will not make "*" character match the initial "." character for historical reasons ( eg files starting with "." are considered hidden , and "." & ".." refer to directories )

Hence `ls` will not show .bashrc , but `ls -a` will show all files.
Similarly , `ls *` will expand into all files except those that start with a "." character.

Change this behaviour with `shopt -s dotglob` which informs bash that "*" must also match the initial "." character.
After this , `ls *` will show .bashrc too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that a leading dot is the convention for "hidden file", and file globbing (which is the name for the use of `*` as "any number of any characters" and `?` as "any one character" and a few others) specifically excludes a leading dot because it means "hidden file".

If you write `ls -l .*` you will match `.bashrc`, but you will also match the special hidden files `.` and `..` which are directories, so to show hidden files you will want something along these lines:

- `ls -ld .*`
- `ls -l .[^.]*`
- `ls -A | grep bash`

`ls -A *bash*` will not show you `.bashrc` because the file globbing is done before the `-A` option takes effect.

If you want to change the way file globbing works with hidden files you can execute `shopt -s dotglob`, either just in the shell to test, or put in your .bash_profile or .bashrc to have it always effective.